# usage of "complement"

Tags: word-usage

[From the Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complement)

> The scarf is a perfect **complement** to her outfit.

This pattern is easy to understand, `A is complement to B`

[From the Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/complement)

> The green wallpaper is the perfect **complement** to the old pine of the dresser.

Again, the same pattern `A is complement to B`.

To make it easier to understand, could I say "B was missing something, A could help"?

The completeness is more about beauty, in particular, some kind of addition to existing beauty.

However, that kind of completeness is probably difficult for someone, like me, to understand. I'd never managed to distinguish my wife's scarves. So, I can't even make up **what B is missing** in any of those examples!

Besides, beauty is somehow a matter of opinion. Are there some other situations where the complement is easier to measure?

For example, could I call my headset a complement to my laptop, which can let me hear whatever I want to listen to without disturbing anyone else?

---

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/complement)

> We had a full **complement** of reporters and photographers along.

This example doesn't use the pattern `A is complement to B`, which makes it difficult to say B is missing what.

Comment: A complement does not supply something "missing", it supplies something _extra_.

Comment: There are several distinct meanings for **complement** (and although it looks similar to the word 'complete' is different). [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/complement)'s meaning **1** is about your scarf example. Meaning **2** is about the reporters. In the scarf example, there was nothing *missing*, and in your headphones example below, they don't *complement* the laptop, they are an *extra*.

Comment: ... and in the answer, that is a distinct mathematical term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let A be an angle in mathematics (specifically an acute angle, that is, between 0 and 90 degrees).  The **complement** of A is the angle which fills up the rest of the gap so as to make 90 degrees together with A.

So if angle B is **the complement** to angle A, then A + B = 90 degrees.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is so clear. Thanks a lot! How about my example of laptop? Are there any other daily life examples for it?

Comment: You could do, if you so wished, but it's the sort of language I'd only really expect to hear in an advertisement. As for the quote from the Cambridge dictionary, "a full complement" means "all the reporters needed to make the party **complete**." The word "complement" itself means "complete-ment", that is, what you need to "complete" something. As such it's usually flowery and pretentious language, although "a full complement" is a common cliche.

Comment: Thank you. So, calling headset a complement to laptop sounds like an advertisement, right? How could I make it not sound like that?

Comment: @RobertH I don't know, I'm not writing your essay. I'd just say that the headphones are a useful accessory or adjunct, unless you really are singing the praises of your system to someone you're trying to persuade that yes, indeed, you *do* have just the best of toys.