# Is it clear and natural to ask the usage by saying "is A with B"?

Tags: word-usage

[A post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/251257/116345) that talks about the usage of "complement" uses this title

> Is "complement" with fact, opinion or both?

in this pattern `is A with B`

Which was trying to ask whether the word "complement" should be used only with fact, opinion or both.

Is it clear and natural to say it that way?

---

**Note:** "complement" there is not used as a term. In other words, "complement" in that context is with the meaning of ["Something that completes, makes up a whole, or brings to perfection"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=complement), rather than a Grammar term.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you. Your answer is very informative. Btw, "complement" in the OP is with the meaning of "Something that completes, makes up a whole, or brings to perfection", rather than a Grammar term.

Comment: Please note: I deleted my comment and have now provided you **with an answer**.

Comment: ["complement" in the OP is with the meaning of= not grammatical. You mean: "complement" as asked by the OP **means**]. A term is another word for a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action or active verb usage:

**- This spice complements the soup.**

**- This answer complements the other answer.**

**- This dress color complements your complexion.**

> "Something that completes, makes up a whole, or brings to perfection",
> as per the OP's question.

"Is complement with fact or opinion", also in the OP's question.

*That phrasing is not grammatical in  English*.
Correct phrasing of that question would be:

***Is the word (term) complement used to express a fact or opinion?***

***complement is either an action/active verb or a noun.***

Noun usage:

- The complement to the book was the preface written by Professor Y.
- The singing was a complement to the dinner party.